# mySQL timeout on alter table

Tags: mysql

I am using mySQL workbench. I have a tiny table (3800 rows) and I am running the following query:

```
alter table tournaments MODIFY COLUMN director_address CHAR(250);
```

I get the following error after 20 seconds:

> Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query.

I have tried changing several settings and nothing is set to 20 seconds, so I don't understand why it disconnects in 20 seconds.

I have gone to Edit->Preferences and set all the timeouts to 600. When I look at the session timeouts nothing is short.

Can anyone help??

Per request, this is the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE tournaments;

CREATE TABLE `tournaments` (
   `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `tournament_master_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
   `name` char(75) NOT NULL,
   `start_dt` date NOT NULL,
   `days_in_tournament` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
   `season_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
   `playing_site` char(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `playing_address` char(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `city` char(50) NOT NULL,
   `state` char(2) NOT NULL,
   `zip` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
   `director` char(50) NOT NULL,
   `phone_number` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
   `email_address` char(80) DEFAULT NULL,
   `director_address` char(200) DEFAULT NULL,
   `co_director1` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `co_director2` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `charity_name` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `charity_donation` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
   `other_event1` char(200) DEFAULT NULL,
   `other_event2` char(200) DEFAULT NULL,
   `other_event3` char(200) DEFAULT NULL,
   `other_event4` char(200) DEFAULT NULL,
   `other_info` char(200) DEFAULT NULL,
   `need_banner` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `scorecard1_games` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
   `scorecard1_quantity` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
   `scorecard2_games` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
   `scorecard2_quantity` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
   `guideline_agreement` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `is_sanctioned` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `flyer_name` char(200) DEFAULT NULL,
   `is_flyer_approved` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `created_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `reported_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `is_posted` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
   `is_complete` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7337 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Also, if it matters (?) I am running workbench on my local machine and connecting to a Network Solutions server where the database is. Other queries execute just fine.

Comment: Does 20 secs seem excessive to you, given your environment (it does to me)? Maybe you could modify your question to show the results of 'SHOW CREATE TABLE tournaments;'.

Comment: Added to the post.